# jQuery Trigger and On in JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, jquery-ui, jquery-events

In the following JSFiddle, I am trying to create a Sortable list using jQuery UI in React.js, so that I can recreate a bug that I am getting in production with proprietary code I'm working on.

Since I can't easily use the Node.js event emitter in JSFiddle, I tried to use jQuery's `trigger` and `on` instead. That isn't working below, so I can't recreate the error.

Here is a link to the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bengrunfeld/zoyeejxr/

If I can get the following code working, then I can move forward in recreating the *real* error I'm having.

EDIT: I've tried just attaching `trigger` and `on` to `document`, but it breaks the jQuery-UI Sortable plugin for some reason.

Le code:

```
_list = {
    fruit: [
    'apple',
    'banana',
    'cherry',
    'date'
    ]
};

var Entry = React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        return (
           <div className="entry">{this.props.content}</div> 
        )
    }
});

var Shop = React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        var data = this.props.data.fruit;

        var fruitOrder = data.map(function(node, i) {
            return (
                <Entry key={i} content={node}>{node}</Entry>
            );
        });

        return (
            <div className="shop">{fruitOrder}</div>
        )
    }
});

function getList() {
  return { data: _list }
}

var Basket = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return getList();
    },
    componentWillMount: function(){
        $('.basket').on('sort', function(data){
            // Show that this works
            console.log('this works');

            // Swap item position in the array to recreate React
            // swapping error
            var tmp = _list.fruit[0];
            _list.fruit[0] = _list.fruit[1];
            _list.fruit[1] = tmp;
            this.setState(getList());
        });
    },
    sortIndexes: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    buttonClicked: function(e){
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="basket">
                <p>Drag and drop the fruits</p>
                <Shop data={this.state.data} />
            </div>
            )
    }
});

React.render(
    <Basket />, 
    document.body
    );


  $('.shop').sortable({
    axis: "y",
    containment: "parent",
    tolerance: "pointer",
    revert: 150,
    start: function (event, ui) {
      ui.item.indexAtStart = ui.item.index();
    },
    stop: function (event, ui) {
      var data = {
        indexStart: ui.item.indexAtStart,
        indexStop: ui.item.index(),
      };
      $('.basket').trigger('sort');
    },
  });
```

Comment: You can't access React rendered DOM elements in `componentWillMount` phase. Use `componentDidMount`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Olim Saidov pointed in his comment, DOM is not yet rendered when `componentWillMount` is called. You should move event binding to `componentDidMount`.

Another issue in your code is that you need to bind `this` in callback to jQuery's `on`.

Try to replace your `componentWillMount` with this code:

```
componentDidMount: function(){
    var _this = this;
    $('.basket').on('sort', function(data){
        console.log('this works');
        var tmp = _list.fruit[0];
        _list.fruit[0] = _list.fruit[1];
        _list.fruit[1] = tmp;
        _this.setState(getList());
    });
},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zoyeejxr/16/

Comment: So the real issue that I'm dealing with is listed here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29725136/jquery-ui-sortable-with-react-js-buggy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29725136/jquery-ui-sortable-with-react-js-buggy). If you'd be able to help me out with this, I'd greatly appreciate it.